# Does taking the negative of the direction ratios of a line change the direction cosines of the line?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

According to what I learnt the direction ratio $(3, -2, 8)$ is same as that of the direction ratio $(-3, 2, -8)$.

Again we know that, if $l$, $m$, $n$ are direction cosines and $a$, $b$, $c$ are direction ratios then,

$l =\displaystyle \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$, $m =\displaystyle \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$ and $n =\displaystyle \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$

So, the two direction ratios will  give two different direction cosines.Again I learnt that the direction cosines of a line is unique. So surely the two different direction cosines will represent two different lines.

I think here both the lines represented by the two direction cosines are the same, only their their direction is opposite to that of each other. Am I correct?

Comment: You might find [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) interesting.

Comment: @HosamHAJEER I already went through Wikipedia but it did not found anything that could answer my question

Comment: "the direction cosines of a line is unique". No, the direction cosines of a *vector* is unique. A vector has a unique direction, but a line does not.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks! That make sense

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Can you please also tell me if the two vectors represented by the two direction cosines will have opposite directions with respect to each other

Comment: Yes, they are opposite.

Comment: @RajeshPaul: This question is very similar to [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4833385/409). Rather than essentially re-post, you should have edited the previous version; an edit will "bump" a question to the top of the Unanswered Queue, so you get that benefit of a new post without cluttering the site with duplicates. (But note that non-substantive edits *just* to bump a question are inappropriate.) No harm done here, but keep this information in mind for the future. (For now, you should delete the previous question.) ... Good luck!

Comment: @Blue Thank you for treating noobs like me with such dignity.I did not know that.I will make sure not to make any duplicate question again, and also deleted the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction cosines are defined for a vector $V \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ not a line.

If $ V = [v_1, v_2, v_3]$ , and if $ a, b, c $ are the angles that the vector $V$ makes with the $x, y, z$ axes, then the direction cosines are given by

$ \alpha = \cos(a) = \dfrac{ v_1  }{ \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2}} $

$ \beta = \cos(b) = \dfrac{ v_2  }{ \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2} }$

$ \gamma = \cos(c) = \dfrac{ v_3  }{ \sqrt{v_1^2 + v_2^2 + v_3^2}} $

From these equations, you can see that if you reverse $V$ into another vector $U = -V$, then the direction cosines of $U$ will be the negative of those of $V$, with corresponding changes to the angles $a,b,c$.

The direction ratios of a vector are just the coordinates of this vector.  So if reverse the vector $V$ into $U = -V$ , the direction ratios will be the negative of those of $V$.

So the answer to your question in the title of this question is YES, taking the negative of the direction ratios (of a vector) changes the direction cosines of the resulting vector to the negative of the original direction cosines.